# using CI_JOB_TOKEN for API call inside CI pipeline returns 404

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, token

I have only these two jobs in my pipeline. The second one is supposed to retrieve a list of all previous jobs.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
   -  echo "build"

test_job:
  image: bash:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - apk add curl
    - |
      curl --header "Job-Token: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/pipelines/${CI_PIPELINE_ID}/jobs"
```

My problem is that the second job returns a 404.

```
{
  "message": "404 Project Not Found"
}
```

This has to be because of authorization issues as the project defintely exists. However I am trying to access the project via API from itself and according to [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html):

> "By default, the allowlist of any project only includes itself."

Which means that `CI_JOB_TOKEN` should have sufficient access.

Further, which confuses me even more, when I replace `"Job-Token: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"` with `"Private-Token: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"`, the curl command returns:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Token was revoked. You have to re-authorize from the user."
}
```

What setings could be set incorrectly or am I using the API wrong?

*Note: I tested the curl with a personal access token and it worked as expected*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job tokens have limited API access. You can't use this jobs API with a job token. Even when added to the allowlist, job tokens are still limited to [specific endpoints](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html), which does not include the jobs *list* API (though you can get job artifacts using a job token).

You will need to use another method to authenticate to this API, such as a project access token, group access token, or similar.